# Convert Number of Decimals Through a Text File

Tags: bash, sed, perl, awk

This question's solution may revolve around perl, sed or awk and unfortunately I am not familiar with any of those.

My purpose is to convert a computer-generated text file to give it more human-readable properties.  To that end, I wish to process all numbers with 10+ decimal digits to something around: just 2.  This should be independent of keywords around them.

Example log file:

```
[General]
Date=2016-01-20
Timestamp=2016-01-20T12:30:00

[Dewpoint]
Low=-17.7041803458378
LTime=14:55
High=-13.1057525836829
HTime=13:42

[Solar]
SunshineHours=4.78333333333332
SunshineHoursToMidnight=0.750000000000001
```

Desired output:

```
[General]
Date=2016-01-20
Timestamp=2016-01-20T12:30:00

[Dewpoint]
Low=-17.70
LTime=14:55
High=-13.11
HTime=13:42

[Solar]
SunshineHours=4.78
SunshineHoursToMidnight=0.75
```

Rounding is not a necessity here, that is truncating would be sufficient for my needs.

How could I achieve this without RTWFM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F"=" -v OFS="=" '
    NF == 2 && $2 ~ /^-?[0-9]*\.[0-9]+$/ {$2 = sprintf("%.2f", $2)} 
    {print}
' file.log
```

That uses `=` as the field separator. For lines with 2 fields and the 2nd field is a float, reformat the 2nd field.

Outputs your sample data as

```
[General]
Date=2016-01-20
Timestamp=2016-01-20T12:30:00

[Dewpoint]
Low=-17.70
LTime=14:55
High=-13.11
HTime=13:42

[Solar]
SunshineHours=4.78
SunshineHoursToMidnight=0.75
```

Answer (score 1):

Passing it through a little regex should work

```
sed -r 's/([0-9]+\.[0-9]{2})[0-9]*/\1/' your_file
```

To quickly explain it's looking for:

- A digit
- A dot
- 2 more digits
- Any number of digits

And it's replacing all of that with just the first three. Essentially chopping off the last part.

That command will just output the changes. Add an `-i` in there if you want it to edit the file directly. If this isn't actually a file, you can pipe and redirect things into `sed` too:

```
$ sed -r 's/([0-9]\.[0-9]{2})[0-9]*/\1/' <<EOF
> [General]
> Date=2016-01-20
> Timestamp=2016-01-20T12:30:00
> 
> [Dewpoint]
> Low=-17.7041803458378
> LTime=14:55
> High=-13.1057525836829
> HTime=13:42
> 
> [Solar]
> SunshineHours=4.78333333333332
> SunshineHoursToMidnight=0.750000000000001
> EOF
[General]
Date=2016-01-20
Timestamp=2016-01-20T12:30:00

[Dewpoint]
Low=-17.70
LTime=14:55
High=-13.10
HTime=13:42

[Solar]
SunshineHours=4.78
SunshineHoursToMidnight=0.75
```

Comment: Thanks - but I would wish it to be more generic (drop any reference to high, low or other keywords).  Will update the question.

Comment: @Tfb9 Updated...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<==)[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(!:)/sprintf("%.2f",$&)/e' log
```

which reprints with precision 2 any floating-point number that follows an `=` and does not precede a `:` (so as to ignore the time fields).

If you don't want to treat integer values as floating point, then it's somewhat simpler to exclude the time fields, and the following should do it:

```
perl -pe 's/[-+]?[0-9]*\.[0-9]+/sprintf("%.2f",$&)/e' log
```

The floating-point regex is taken from [Matching Floating Point Numbers with a Regular Expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html)

Comment: I wonder if the decimal point should be optional. I wonder if `a=42` should become `a=42.00`. The OP would have to decide.

Comment: @glennjackman thanks, yes in fact I contemplated that (especially as it simplifies the exclusion of the time fields) but decided to keep the definition of "floating point" as canonical as possible.  I've edit that in as an option.